# How to send request from IPv6 Address from box which has dula IP (i.e both IPV4 & IPv6)

Tags: ip-address

I have linux box which serves as client and has dual IP i.e both ipv4 & IPv6. I would like to send some request to from this client box via its IPV6 address. By default server always receives the request from IPv4 address. We can not make any changes to server. Is there some easy way/configuration which can be done on client machine so that request is sent via its ipv6 address. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client, make sure you're using an IPv6 socket, not an IPv4 socket:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

The `AF_INET6` specifies IPv6.  `AF_INET` specifies IPv4...